# How to define my own filter while working with Telerik RadGridView control?

Tags: c#, xaml, filter, telerik, radgridview

I'm working on a C# application, where I'm trying to create my own filtering mechanism for filtering a Telerik `RadGridView` control.

My `RadGridView` control looks as follows (in the `xaml` file, I've left some open lines for showing the part where I define my filter):

```xml
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="PartsGridView"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     CanUserFreezeColumns="False"
                     FilteringMode="Popup"
                     FilterOperatorsLoading="Grid_FilterOperatorsLoading"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding PagedSource, ElementName=PartsRadDataPager}"
                     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPart}"
                     SelectionMode="Single"
                     ShowInsertRow="False"
                     EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                     RowLoaded="PartsGridView_RowLoaded"
                     FieldFilterEditorCreated="FieldFilterEditorCreated"
                     IsFilteringAllowed="True"
                     DistinctValuesLoading="PartsGridView_DistinctValuesLoading"
                     Grouped="PartsGridView_Grouped">
    <telerik:RadGridView.GroupDescriptors>
        <telerik:GroupDescriptor Member="Name" DisplayContent="Article"/>
    </telerik:RadGridView.GroupDescriptors>
    <telerik:RadGridView.FilterDescriptors/>
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        ...
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Article.CustomerReference}" 
                                    Header="Client"
                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                    Name="Client">
        
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.FilteringControl>
                <local:Myfilter Column="{Binding ElementName=Client}"/>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.FilteringControl>
            
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

The corresponding source code is as follows (I've only shown the `OnFilter`, it's the idea to extend the filtering possibilities to regular expressions, but let's start making the regular filter work first):

```
public partial class MyFilter : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl, 
                                IFilteringControl
{
    private GridViewDataColumn column;
    private CompositeFilterDescriptor compositeFilter;
    private Telerik.Windows.Data.FilterDescriptor textFilter;

    private void OnFilter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //var reg = new Regex(textBox.Text.Replace("*", ".*"));

        // var descriptor = new FilterDescriptor<string> 
        //                  { FilteringExpression = o => reg.IsMatch(o) };

        compositeFilter = new CompositeFilterDescriptor();

        textFilter = new Telerik.Windows.Data.FilterDescriptor(Column.Name
            , Telerik.Windows.Data.FilterOperator.IsEqualTo
            , null);

        compositeFilter.FilterDescriptors.Add(textFilter);

        textFilter.Value = TextBox;

        if (!Column.DataControl.FilterDescriptors.Contains(compositeFilter))
        {
            Column.DataControl.FilterDescriptors.Add(compositeFilter);
        }

        IsActive = true;
    }
```

When debugging, I go into the `OnFilter()` function but instead of just filtering, I don't see any data in the `RadGridView` anymore.

Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:** In case the question is not clear, don't hesitate asking for more information.

Comment: Nobody has an idea?

Comment: `Telerik.Windows.Data.FilterOperator.IsEqualTo` is not your friend in this case.

Comment: @codewerfer: Thanks for your reply. What's the problem with `Telerik.Windows.Data.FilterOperator.IsEqualTo`? Bugs, case (in)sensitivity, ...? Obviously I'm not planning to use this in case of regular expressions.

Comment: Its been more then 10 years since I last worked with Telerik. A couple of things flew to mind. (based on previous comment) Does Column.Name can be null or is it empty string? You mentioned  you don't see data into RadGridView but I don't see data is bind to it in the OnFilter method? Or maybe because this filtering is server side you forgot the UpdatePanel? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void OnFilter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //var reg = new Regex(textBox.Text.Replace("*", ".*"));

    // var descriptor = new FilterDescriptor<string> 
    //                  { FilteringExpression = o => reg.IsMatch(o) };

    //compositeFilter = new CompositeFilterDescriptor();

    textFilter = new Telerik.Windows.Data.FilterDescriptor(Column.Name
        , Telerik.Windows.Data.FilterOperator.IsEqualTo
        , null);

    //compositeFilter.FilterDescriptors.Add(textFilter);

    textFilter.Value = TextBox;

    if (!Column.DataControl.FilterDescriptors.Contains(textFilter))
    {
        Column.DataControl.FilterDescriptors.Add(textFilter);
    }

    IsActive = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can also try this:

```
private void OnFilter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    compositeFilter = new CompositeFilterDescriptor();
    textFilter = new Telerik.Windows.Data.FilterDescriptor(Column.Name, Telerik.Windows.Data.FilterOperator.IsEqualTo, null);
    compositeFilter.FilterDescriptors.Add(textFilter);
    textFilter.Value = TextBox;
    if (!Column.DataControl.FilterDescriptors.Contains(compositeFilter))
    {
        Column.DataControl.FilterDescriptors.Add(compositeFilter);
    }
    IsActive = true;
}
```